# how to remove the navigation bar for individual tabs from interfaceBuilder

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i created a tabbar with navigation controller for individual tabs in xcode 4.0 using InterfaceBuilder.previous week ive changed to ios5 and i m not able to find the option to change the navigation controller to view controller in IntefaceBuilder.could u guys help me out by providing me a screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag the controller type onto the tab bar at the bottom and delete the unneeded ones.

Comment: there was an easy way to do dis in xcode 4.0.u click the tabbar and on the inspector u can change from navigationcontroller to viewController.is der any option available as i have mentioned above?

Comment: Not available any more.  That old way meant you could easily set something incorrectly.  The way I suggested above, prevents some of those issues and is much more tightly integrated to the actual UI.

Comment: so i got to delete the UINavigationController under TabBar and Place a ViewController?

Comment: I would too, if Xcode 5 existed :P  XCode 4.2 is way better than 3 and < 4.2 :D